# Get Generic Type of Generic Type

Tags: java, generics, types

If I have

```
public abstract class SomeType<T extends SomeOtherType> {}

public class WrapperType<U extends SomeType<T>> {}
```

Is there a way to modify the latter signature (which is an error 'cannot resolve symbol "T"') so that I can use the generic type in WrapperType, say for `List<T>` or something analogous?

(If I have posed this question using the wrong terminology, I'd appreciate the corrections.)

Answer (score 5):

It's quite simple once you realize what's going on.  You didn't define `T` in the scope of the class `WrapperType`.  Declare it with at least the same bounds as in `SomeType`.

```
class WrapperType<T extends SomeOtherType, U extends SomeType<T>> {}
```

Comment: Yep, I figured this out right after you. I've deleted my answer, will approve yours when it lets me. edit: though, interestingly, order didn't seem to matter.

Comment: @Logan If the extra type parameter is going to be annoying, you can also use `WrapperType<U extends SomeType<?>>`, but only if you don't need to use `T` in the body of the class.

Comment: @Logan The order not mattering is essential. Otherwise you couldn't do `MyClass<T extends SomeType<U>, U extends SomeOtherType<T>>`.

Comment: You can just use `<U extends SomeType>` if you don't need the inner type. But I do, hence this question :)

Comment: @Logan You can, but raw types are evil.